# Loop category including custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

For the last two days I tried to loop through a parent category and display my custom post type posts within it.

I've created a custom post type with the name: mentors_post_type and participants_post_type, where I use category as a taxonomy.

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
```

Both post types are organized in categories for each year: 2016, 2017, 2018, etc. Somehow I can't achieve to loop through the years category and display the posts and sub-categories like:

```
(year category)
2017 (subcategory)
all posts with custom post type: mentors_post_type 
2016 (subcategory)
all posts with custom post type: mentors_post_type
```

No matter how I've tried it, I don't get any posts from the custom post type or all posts from the custom post type (can't filter them by category). When I just get the category names and their post-counts, the post-counts are right.

Comment: If I get you right, what about something like this: https://gist.github.com/mayeenulislam/f1c8459644b294185ceac435d168446a ? It's not the exact answer, that's why not posting here.

Answer (score -1):

You would do something along these lines using the category id, and an array of the post_types within your loop

```
query_posts( array(
 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'report', 'opinion', bookmark' ),
 'cat' => 3,
 'orderby' => 'date',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'showposts' => 5 )
 );
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Never use `query_posts()` - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22728

Comment: thanks to booth of you! 
i'm pretty sure i've tried it that way… but now it works. great! thanks a lot!
but is there a way to seperate the child-categories?

i need the title of the child-category and a single ul for the posts.